# C# Using System.Data.DataSet for ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dataset

I was wondering if System.Data.DataSet is inside the .NET framework or the .NET Core framework or both.
And if it is only in the .NET framework, what do people use as a replacement in .NET Core framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System.Data.DataSet is part of .NET Standard so it has to be a part of .NET Framework and .NET Core

[click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset?view=netframework-4.7.2#applies-to)